# Highlight txt files but not help files

Tags: vim

I would like to apply the following `autocmd`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt set filetype=markdown
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt colorscheme OceanicNext
```

However, I do not want this to apply to any vim `help` files that are loaded whenever I do `:h <something>`. Is there a way to exclude that from the autocmd?

Comment: [Filename patterns](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-patterns) don't allow negation. The way to work around is: implement a function to be called on the event and check full path in the function. See an example: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11397 `vim`'s help files are `$VIMRUNTIME/doc/*.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileType` event whenever possible.

Use `setfiletype` to set filetype if it wasn't already set.

> ~/.vim/ftdetect/markdown.vim

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt setf FALLBACK markdown
```

> ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim

```
setlocal foo bar
```